# Append text on lines NOT matching pattern

Tags: linux, awk, sed, mysql

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
VALUES (
 39741633
 49302045
 0
 44
  '{"CustomerName":"S","CustomerMobile":"8","CustomerEmail":"","VersionId":"5","CityId":"2","CampaignId":"1","InquirySourceId":"3","Eagerness":"-1","ApplicationId":"2","BranchId":"3","AssignedDealerId":"2","DMSInqNo":"45"}'
  NULL
  0
  '2021-11-09 19:11:50'
  NULL
  1
  29
  NULL
);
INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
VALUES (
 39741635
 49970365
 0
 30
  '{"CustomerName":"A","CustomerEmail":"As@gmail.com","CustomerMobile":"9","VersionId":"6","InquirySourceId":"1","Eagerness":"-1","IsCorporate":"z","CampaignId":"8","BranchId":"3","ApplicationId":"1","Location":{"City":{"CityId":"1"},"Area":{"AreaId":"4"}},"CouponCode":null,"CwOfferId":"0","AssignedDealerId":"0","PinCode":""}'
  NULL
  0
  '2021-11-09 19:11:51'
  NULL
  1
  29
  NULL
);
```

I have these insert statements extracted out of binlogs. They were not exactly like this, I have changed them a little, but I am stuck. I need to convert them into actual insert statements. If you see I need to add commas at end of each line after the second line (INSERT INTO `db`.`table` VALUES (), for each insert statement. That means add commas after two lines till 11 lines, then again start after INSERT INTO and repeat.

I tried to google and found this

`sed '/INSERT/{n;n;n;n;n;s/$/,/}' teststring.txt` --> this will put comma on fifth line after insert. The problem is if I run it again for the sixth line

`sed '/INSERT/{n;n;n;n;n;n;s/$/,/}' teststring.txt` , then it replaces the earlier comma placed by the first SED command

This is how the file should look.

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
VALUES (
 39741633,
 49302045,
 0,
 44,
 '{"CustomerName":"S","CustomerMobile":"8","CustomerEmail":"","VersionId":"5","CityId":"2","CampaignId":"1","InquirySourceId":"3","Eagerness":"-1","ApplicationId":"2","BranchId":"3","AssignedDealerId":"2","DMSInqNo":"45"}',
  NULL,
  0,
  '2021-11-09 19:11:50',
  NULL,
  1,
  29,
  NULL
);
INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
VALUES (
 39741635,
 49970365,
 0,
 30,
  '{"CustomerName":"A","CustomerEmail":"As@gmail.com","CustomerMobile":"9","VersionId":"6","InquirySourceId":"1","Eagerness":"-1","IsCorporate":"z","CampaignId":"8","BranchId":"3","ApplicationId":"1","Location":{"City":{"CityId":"1"},"Area":{"AreaId":"4"}},"CouponCode":null,"CwOfferId":"0","AssignedDealerId":"0","PinCode":""}',
  NULL,
  0,
  '2021-11-09 19:11:51',
  NULL,
  1,
  29,
  NULL
);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You could match all lines NOT containing some string, and append the comma:

```
sed '/.*VALUES.*\|.*INSERT.*\|);$/! s/$/,/' your_file
```

The way it's working is as follows:

- I match any lines containing either `VALUES`, `INSERT` or ending with `);`.
- This is done by chaining together the different strings with `\|`.
- These are then 'negated' them with the `!` (so only lines NOT containing these
  strings are actually matched).
- I then append a comma to those lines.

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i` to do the
substitution in-place:

```
sed -i '/.*VALUES.*\|.*INSERT.*\|);$/! s/$/,/' your_file
```

#### Edit

As pointed out by @they in the comments below, this command will also place a
comma on the last line of each INSERT statement (I'm not sure if this is a
problem for you):

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
VALUES (
 39741633,
  .
  .
  .
  29,
  NULL,  <--- unecessary comma here
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that did the trick

Comment: @AvinashPawar I'm glad it helped you - maybe you can upvote/accept the answer

Comment: Note that this inserts a comma before the last `);` in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @they thanks for pointing that out - I updated the answer to make sure people know.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/INSERT INTO/{n;n;s/$/,/}' teststring.txt
```

I missed the `-i` option, this SED command added a comma at the end of the second line after INSERT INTO.
I am able to do what I wanted to, but I had to run that command repeatedly for 10 lines by increasing `n;` in each command so the next command for the third line would be

```
`sed -i '/INSERT INTO/{n;n;n;s/$/,/}' teststring.txt`.
```

Here there are three `n;` and in the first command there were two `n;`.

I would appreciate if any one has a better way of doing this :-).

Comment: This seems to add one of the missing commas, but not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we find a line starting with the string `VALUES`, append the next line to the editing buffer in `sed`.  Repeat this until the buffer ends with `);`.  Then replace all newlines that are not flanked by a parenthesis on any side with a comma.

```
/^VALUES/ {
    # Loop until the buffer ends with ");".
    # The N command reads the next line and appends
    # it to the buffer, with a newline character as delimiter.
    :again
    N
    /);$/ !b again

    # Replace all newlines with commas,
    # but only if the newline is not immediately
    # next to a parenthesis.
    s/\([^(]\)\n\([^)]\)/\1,\2/g
}
```

This could be used as a separate `sed` script:

```bsh
sed -f thescript file
```

... or directly on the command line:

```bsh
sed -e '/^VALUES/ {' \
    -e ':again' \
    -e 'N; /);$/ !b again' \
    -e 's/\([^(]\)\n\([^)]\)/\1,\2/g; }' file
```

Given the document in the question, this would generate syntactically correct SQL looking like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
VALUES (
 39741633, 49302045, 0, 44,  '{"CustomerName":"S","CustomerMobile":"8","CustomerEmail":"","VersionId":"5","CityId":"2","CampaignId":"1","InquirySourceId":"3","Eagerness":"-1","ApplicationId":"2","BranchId":"3","AssignedDealerId":"2","DMSInqNo":"45"}',  NULL,  0,  '2021-11-09 19:11:50',  NULL,  1,  29,  NULL
);
INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
VALUES (
 39741635, 49970365, 0, 30,  '{"CustomerName":"A","CustomerEmail":"As@gmail.com","CustomerMobile":"9","VersionId":"6","InquirySourceId":"1","Eagerness":"-1","IsCorporate":"z","CampaignId":"8","BranchId":"3","ApplicationId":"1","Location":{"City":{"CityId":"1"},"Area":{"AreaId":"4"}},"CouponCode":null,"CwOfferId":"0","AssignedDealerId":"0","PinCode":""}',  NULL,  0,  '2021-11-09 19:11:51',  NULL,  1,  29,  NULL
);
```

If you want the exact output that you have in the question, replace the last substitution with

```
s/\([^(]\)\(\n\)\([^)]\)/\1,\2\3/g
```

Instead of replacing the newlines with commas, this inserts a comma before each newline.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have a consistent number of values (rows) to insert, we can count them and append a comma to all but the last:

```
awk 'i>0 {i--; $0 = $0 ","} /^VALUES/ {i=11} 1' datafile.txt
```

There are actually three statements in this `awk` program. You could rewrite it like this, spread across several lines. (All lines in the program are applied in order to each line of input.)

```
awk '
    i>0 { i--; $0 = $0 "," }    # If we are counting, decrement the counter and append comma
    /^VALUES/ { i=11 }          # "VALUES" resets the counter for 12 values/rows
    1                           # Print the current line
' datafile.txt
```

Sample output (first stanza)

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
VALUES (
 39741633,
 49302045,
 0,
 44,
  '{"CustomerName":"S","CustomerMobile":"8","CustomerEmail":"","VersionId":"5","CityId":"2","CampaignId":"1","InquirySourceId":"3","Eagerness":"-1","ApplicationId":"2","BranchId":"3","AssignedDealerId":"2","DMSInqNo":"45"}',
  NULL,
  0,
  '2021-11-09 19:11:50',
  NULL,
  1,
  29,
  NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two-line pattern space,
and append commas to all lines that
don't have INSERT or );
And owing to 2 lines in the pattern space, the line around INSERT and ); too are not appended to.

```
sed -e '
  $!N;/INSERT\|);$/!{s/\n/,&/;P;D;}
' file
```